# Understanding segmentation fault error for macOS

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

When running my application, I receive a segmentation fault then a window pops up letting me know that:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0x0000000128108eb3 WP_ForcePowerRun(gentity_s*, forcePowers_t, usercmd_s*) + 4435
0x0000000128107c15 WP_ForcePowersUpdate(gentity_s*, usercmd_s*) + 501
0x0000000128033bc1 ClientThink_real(gentity_s*, usercmd_s*) + 1153
0x0000000128035843 ClientThink(int, usercmd_s*) + 995
0x00000001280bf68a NPC_Think(gentity_s*) + 1786
0x000000012805ef4a G_RunFrame(int) + 1418
0x000000010d28b4d0 SV_Frame(int, float) + 576
0x000000010d266c4c Com_Frame() + 588
0x000000010d2d7525 main + 389
0x00007fff2046af3d start + 1
```

So I have two questions:

1. What are the numbers on the right side of each function i.e +4435, +501, etc.?
2. Is there any way to determine the specific line number where the segmentation fault is happening?

Comment: Do you have `addr2line`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Those are the offset, aka how many bytes after the beginning of the function the fault happened.
2. You can compile with debug symbols and use a debugger like GDB.